# Cross-compilation with GHC

Tags: haskell, cross-compiling, ghc

Is it possible to do [cross-compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) with the [Glasgow Haskell Compiler](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) for common architectures?

If not, is this feature planned to be developed in the near future?

Comment: It's a common question, but a good one.  The only cross compilation I've heard of with a GHC derivative is HaLVM, otherwise the answer is 'wait for it or contribute to it', as dons says.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<strike>As of this moment (GHC 7.0) GHC does not support cross-compilation.</strike>

As of 2013, "support for cross-compilation works reasonably well in GHC 7.8.1".

See the status on the [CrossCompilation](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation) wiki page.

---

*Discussion*

GHC has always supported self-cross-compilation (i.e. you can [port GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Porting) to a new architecture). However, GHC as a cross-compiler, that runs on a host, but produces binaries that target another, has not been supported.

As of GHC 7 though, with the new LLVM backend, work [is being undertaken](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation) to add cross-compilation support. 
Status appears to be, [from Mark Lentczner](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation#March2011:MarkLentczner), *"At this point I can build and link and run a stage1 cross-compiler."* So stay tuned for GHC 7.2

Comment: Is there a blog post or some article that goes step-by-step writing some Haskell code, and then cross compiling it to create a Windows, OSX, Linux, 32bit & 64bit binary?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai There is a new wiki page with further instructions: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling

Comment: @amoebe I've read that before, and I can't make heads or tails out of it.

Comment: The wiki pages you've linked to talk mainly about how to cross-compile _GHC_, not how to cross-compile arbitrary projects.